# Flexbox grid with multiple size flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to specifically do this to div elements:

[image]

```
<span class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <div class="big"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</span>
```

With flexbox? Here is a fiddle where I've been playing around but couldn't get it to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/kwqp4mmj/

And is it possible to make them repeat every 10 divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with nested flexboxes:

```css
flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.big {
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  background-color: black;
}
div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: black;
}
div + div { margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <flex-item>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </flex-item>
  <flex-item class="big"></flex-item>
  <flex-item>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>

<br><hr><br>

<flex-container>
  <flex-item class="big"></flex-item>
  <flex-item>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </flex-item>
  <flex-item>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </flex-item>
</flex-container>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwqp4mmj/2/)

Comment: Good answer ! but I thought the OP wanted a singled container (I can be wrong)